# Add A New KeyFrame to Timeline While an Animation is Executing

Tags: animation, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to modify a [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) while it is running, for example in response to a mouse-click I want to change the target value of the animation. I have tried several methods to do this including (in a mouse clicked handler) :

1. Pausing the animation by calling `pause()` on the `Timeline`, clearing the `KeyFrames` `ObservableList`, adding a new `KeyFrame` and calling `play()` on the `Timeline`.
2. Creating a new KeyFrame with a Cue-name, adding the new frame to the Observable list and calling `jumpTo(cueName)` on the `Timeline`.

Some example code is:

```
String cueName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(myObject.rotateProperty(), -90 + 180.0 * Math.random(), new CustomInterpolator());
KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), cueName, kv);
startupTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
startupTimeline.jumpTo(cueName);
startupTimeline.play();
```

Neither of these appear to work, the animation just stops.

Should I be able to modify the KeyFrame list of an existing Timeline or do I need to create a new Timeline if I want to change an animation while it is executing?

Comment: Good suggestion, James_D. I didn't know that such a class existed. I am actually trying to 'bend' `Timeline` in a way such that the position calculated by my custom interpolater is independent of the fractional value passed into it. It's never a good thing to try and make something do what it was not intended for and AnimationTimer may be better suited. Please put your comment as an answer and I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, a `Timeline` can't be changed in that manner once it has started playing. The issue is that you might change the total cycle duration, which would confuse all the interpolation computations.

You probably need an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) for this. `AnimationTimer` has an abstract `handle(long timestamp)` method which takes a time stamp (in nano-seconds), and is invoked every time the scene graph is rendered. So you can do something like:

```
AnimationTimer animation = new AnimationTimer() {

    private long startTime = -1;

    @Override
    public void handle(long timestamp) {
        if (startTime == -1) {
            startTime = timestamp ;
        }

        long totalElapsedNanoseconds = timestamp - startTime ;
        // update UI based on elapsed time...
    }
}
```

The `handle()` method is invoked on the JavaFX Application Thread, so it is safe to update the UI, and to reference any variables that are only changed on the same thread.

Comment: This is exactly the right class to use for what I want to achieve.